# Magento contact form in CMS page

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, forms, contact-us, cms-block

I'm new in magento and I wonder how to create a form in a CMS page and receive the information by email.

I did some research on the internet but I did not find explicit answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you login **Magento admin ->  CMS -> Pages**

Select your page and input your HTML code as you normally would on any other information you include the page, then select **Content** tab and add it.

The below lines to add your **cms -> page**:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: It seesms that @keyurshah 's answer and this answer are same. If you have further points other than Keyur's, edit your answer and post it.

Comment: I made custom layout page for cms page and in that when i use this code to add contact form it is showing entered code in cms editor not form. Please help me.

Comment: How to add Feedback form to home page  as static like https://snag.gy/eKHyw9.jpg, code : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0  @East

Answer (score 4):

@mbalparda answer is right, but it partially answer the question. In short, it gives you a perfect hint on how you can include a contact-form block inside cms page. But what about adding a custom form in CMS Page? For this, you can refer below answer.

### Step 1 : Create a form

First, you need to create a form that you need to include in CMS Pages. In its simplest form, you should define a new form template for this.

File : `app\design\frontend\[package]\[theme]\template\custom\yourform.phtml`

```
<form action="some/action/" name="form-name" id="form-id" >
   <!-- form inputs come here -->
</form>
```

### Step 2 : Include Your Custom Form in CMS Page

Go to the CMS Page content section and add below content.

```
 {{block type="core/template" template="custom/yourform.phtml"}}
```

We are taking the advantage of ***block-directives*** here. You can insert any block in CMS page like this. This will use your custom form template and render its content inside CMS Page.

Answer (score 3):

Above answer is right but there are some suggestion for this case.

### 1.Change form action post url:

Change the action form  `/contacts/index/post` to custom url like `/contacts/index/custompost`.Because of after form submitting.Custom will redirect to `contacts/index/index`  instead of `custom cms page` because of code at **postAction** function of **Mage_Contacts_IndexController** `($this->_redirect('*/*/');)`.

So,you need to [override Mage_Contacts Indexcontroller](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/) and will `add a new` action `custompostAction` .

Copy all code of `postAction` function to `custompostAction` and just change

> ```
>    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
>       to
>
>       $backUrl=Mage::getUrl().'cmsPageInd';
>       $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
> ```

### Call form block from Design tab:

Instead call of form from Content,call the code at Design tab(Layout Update XML)

```
<reference name="content">
  <block  type="core/template" name="CmscontactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/custompost"/ >
</reference>
```

Comment: thank you all for your response . its works but i have another matter , the form didn't do anything  I want to recover data from my form to my adresse mail

Comment: This was hugely helpful and exactly what I was after (namely the custompostAction bit). Thank you once again Amit Bera :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<!– CONTACT FORM –>
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
<!– END OF CONTACT FORM –>
```

in any CMS page. See [this](https://inchoo.net/magento/contact-form-in-magento/) page for some more info.

Comment: to avoid form_action issue we have to write form_action="{{store direct_url=”contacts”}}/index/post" . correct me if am wrong @mbalparda

Answer (score 1):

1. First login in your magento admin
2. Go to your CMS> Manage Pages interface
3. Once there, input your HTML as you normally would on any other page
4. Once you are happy with HTML part, add this lines:

> {{block type=”core/template” name=”contactForm” form_action=”{{store
>   direct_url=”contacts”}}/index/post” template=”contacts/form.phtml”}}

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Shash thx its works.so how i can recover the new inputs that i add in my new form

Comment: please ask new question for that @djodev

Comment: ok i did @Keyur Shah

Comment: How to add Feedback form to home page  as static like https://snag.gy/eKHyw9.jpg, code : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I'm using Magento 2 and the answers here are for Magento 1.x.

This is the shortcode syntax that worked for me in Magento 2:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```