# Custom form for getting customer details?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9 in my ecommerce site. I had created on page, in that page i have an textbox if i enter customer mail address on that textbox and submit. After that i get customer information. Plz suggest me some idea about this

Comment: Is this text box just for and protected by the admin?

Comment: just textbox only if i enter my mail and submit after that show my details

Comment: Is it publicly available on the frontend though?

Comment: yes user also can enter

Comment: Ok, well there is a security issue here then because any person could just randomly put in another persons email address and see all the details about them. Aside from your original request being a custom module that wouldn't take too long to write, i would consider the implications of providing such an easy access form publicly.

Comment: No actually i am using different purpose not for that

Answer (score 0):

You can call the contact form in your page using this:

```
<!– CONTACT FORM –>
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
<!– END OF CONTACT FORM –>
```

For more info on this topic please see

http://inchoo.net/magento/contact-form-in-magento/
and
[Magento contact form in CMS page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67470/magento-contact-form-in-cms-page)

But if you want create a custom form you can use this module http://mageme.com/magento-extensions/magento-custom-form-builder-designer-webforms-professional-edition.html

Comment: i am not asking contact form plz check my question

Comment: I would call custom contact form template and remove wherever I don't need and it will work. if not use magento webfom module

Comment: i need an textbox if user enter their mail and submit it will display details

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I suggest you below things

1) on button click make ajax call and data to your controller

On your controller get Customer data by this code

```
<?php
 $customer_email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email'); //get your post value
 $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
 $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
 $customer->loadByEmail($customer_email); //load customer by email id
 //use
 echo $customer->getId();
 echo $customer->getFirstName(); 
 //print_r($customer->getData());
```

and retuen the data that you want.