# Problem placing the contact form in a CMS page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to place my "contact us" form in another CMS page following [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/67486/51693) answer. 
i.e.:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="{{store direct_url='contacts'}}/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

But this is all I get as the output:
[image]

**EDIT**
[image]

I am placing the variable from the above answer in the "content" of the CMS page.

Comment: Your code is write you just used in wrong place see my answer

Comment: @jurgis, the answer from Kumar M is right.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora whats wrong with using Ansar Husain answer? (Since that works for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have pasted it in editor mode which make any text into `html entity encoded format`.

So try **disabling** editor mode and then paste it in `textarea(not in wysying editor)` and save.

Also as I can see you have used `{{ and }}` inside `{{ and }}` so script parser will think its getting closed when 1st time `}}` was called. That's why next to 1st `}}` other content is visible.

Simply means you can not put a variable inside a variable; here `{{block}}` will be treated as variable as well.

You can use form_action like this `/contacts/index/post`.

Comment: I also thought so, but I cant seem to get it working either way. Please see my edit

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: ah okay, this is the comprehensive answer I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it will work for you

> {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm"
>   form_action="/contacts/index/post"
>   template="contacts/form.phtml"}}

Comment: this does work, but do you know why I dont need to use `{{store direct_url='contacts'}}` ?

Comment: @JurģisTomsLiepiņš, Magento is not able to parse **`{{`** within another {{...}}.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora well thats how it looks to me too, but other people are claiming it works for them....

Comment: I have created a custom PHP file under app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/top_selling_items_list/top_selling.php, what is my block type in cms. mine getting error - {{block type="top_selling_items_list" template="top_selling_items_list/top_selling.php"}} @Ansar Husain

Comment: change  type="top_selling_items_list" use here class=" block class path " like Vendor\Module\Block\ClassName @Gem

Comment: @AnsarHusain Getting confused, could you pls write clearly with example? Thanks.

Comment: sorry @Gem i was telling you M2 process , it seems you need help in M1.

Comment: @AnsarHusain May i know for M1?

Comment: May i know what exactly error you are getting@Gem